Proxy socket.io with from react to nestjs
I am currently working with :

React JS with http-proxy-middleware
NestJS exposing websocket via gateways

I am trying to access my gateways at the same url using proxy but it does not work.
Here is my configuration :
conversation.ts:
socket = io('/service-conversation');

setupProxy.js :
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api',
    })
  );
  app.use(
    'socket.io',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
      ws: true,
    })
  );
};

gateway.ts :
@WebSocketGateway({
  cors: true,
  namespace: 'service-conversation',
})
export class ConversationGateway {
  @WebSocketServer() webSocketServer: Server;

To give some insight I tried :

connecting directly without proxy using socket = io('http://localhost:3000/service-conversation'); it works but as I want it deployed on the same url on prod it is not the right solution
removing the 'socket.io' from app.use, it works (using postman) but frontend does not work anymore as everything is redirected to localhost:3000
putting the 'socket.io' inside createProxyMiddleware it does not work createProxyMiddleware('socket.io', {...
replacing the 'socket.io' by 'service-conversation' it does not work

